# сохранить значения в localStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Прошу помочь, не могу разобраться как сохранить есть или нет класса в локал сторидж.  Может подскажите, как сохранять эти моменты. перечитал много, разобраться с темой не могу(

```
let b = document.querySelector(".page");
        let a = document.querySelector(".mask");
        let pageColor = localStorage.getItem("classList");

        if (pageColor) {
            b.classList("read");
        }
        a.addEventListener("click", dark);

        function dark() {
            let selectedColor =  b.classList.toggle("read").checked = true;
            localStorage.setItem("tema", selectedColor);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

В localStorage можно хранить только строку.

Сделайте так

```
const settings = {
    selectedColor:  b.classList.toggle("read").checked = true
}

localStorage.setItem("tema", JSON.stringify(settings));
```

Получаем данные из localStorage

```
let selectedColor = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tema"));
```

Т.е. при записи любого значения в localStorage вам его необходимо сконвертировать в строку.
Когда достаете значение из localStorage, необходимо привести данные к нужному типу.

Имена(ключи) localStorage должны быть одинаковыми.
Ключей и хранилищ может быть много.

Comment: а если сохранять состояние страницы при прослушивании музыки, тасклист и т.д?   всегда нужно конвертировать в JSON и потом как-то доставать ?

Comment: Что бы сохранить, вам надо ваше значение сконвертировать в строку. Самый простой способ - положить все нужные значения в json и превратить их в строку JSON.stringify. Когда страница загружается, достаете значение, парсите JSON.parse и получаете полный набор настроек. И расставляйте оттуда значения в свое приложение

Comment: в написанном ответе всегда значение: checked = true и при нажатии тема не меняется ((    я видимо, что то и здесь не так делаю(

Comment: `let selectedColor =  b.classList.toggle("read").checked = true;` Вы значение присвоили а дальше ничего нет. Но это к вопросу не относится. Удалось разобраться с сохранение и получением данных из localStorage?

Comment: сохранить да. спасибо. но сохраняет не тот режим который установлен после изменения. всегда возвращает фон ред. а чтоб менялось и сохранялось то состояние когда вышли не получается(

Comment: Сохранилось то, что было на момент сохранения. Что бы сохранялось все на момент закрытия, это вам надо прикрутить отслеживать событие закрытия сайта и сохранять там.