# Как сохранить данные таблицы в local storage?

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Нужно сохранить данные таблицы в localstorage, чтобы после перезагрузки введенные данные погружались оттуда.
HTML

```
 function create_tr(table_id) {
let table_body = document.getElementById(table_id),
    first_tr   = table_body.firstElementChild,
    tr_clone = first_tr.cloneNode(true);

table_body.append(tr_clone);

clean_first_tr(table_body.firstElementChild);
 }

function clean_first_tr(firstTr) {
let children = firstTr.children;

children = Array.isArray(children) ? children : Object.values(children);
children.forEach(x=>{
    if(x !== firstTr.lastElementChild) {
        x.firstElementChild.value = '';
    }
});
 }



   function remove_tr(This) {
if(This.closest('tbody').childElementCount == 1)
{
    alert("You Don't have Permission to Delete This ?");
}else{
    This.closest('tr').remove();
}
 }

    HTML
  <div class="container">
     <table class="_table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Название лекарства</th>
        <th>Кратность приёма</th>
        <th>Время приёма</th>
        <th width="50px">
            <div class="action_container">
                <button class="success" 
     onclick="create_tr('table_body')">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table_body">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form_control" id="name" 
         placeholder="Парлазин">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form_control" id="taking" 
          placeholder="1 таблетка 2 раза в день">
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea class="form_control" id="time" 
           placeholder="Утром и вечером"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="action_container">
                <button class="danger" onclick="remove_tr(this)">
                    <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </td>
       </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: Посмотрите здесь [https://ru.stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452944/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-localstorage/1452946#1452946)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [сохранить значения в localStorage](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452944/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-localstorage)