# Пермоментное изменение Js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Краткий вопрос
возможно ли сделать так чтобы изменение сделанное с помощью `document.getElementById("").innerHTM` сохранилось навсегда

либо что то похожее на `document.getElementById("").innerHTM` должно сохранится для всех юзеров по типу

---

первоначальное состояние: 1

ввод в специальные окно: 5

обновление страницы

первоначальное состояние: 5

---

и чтобы это "первоначальное состояние" было у всех юзеров сайта 5

Comment: не обязательно document.getElementById("").innerHTM можно что то похожее

Comment: Краткий ответ: нет

Comment: [Можно использовать localStorage](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452944/1452946#1452946), если вы хотите, что бы для пользователя, после перезагрузки страницы, показывалось введенное им ранее значение. [Документация по localStorage](https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage)

Comment: сохранилось где?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: сохранилось для всех юзеров сайта

Answer (score 2):

То о чём Вы думаете - это работа с данными. Ответ - да, можно, но не так как Вы ожидаете. Потому что данные должны храниться не на клиенте, а на сервере, в виду того что, клиентов много, а сервер один и он, собственно, занимается обработкой и предоставлением информации.
В данном случае следует создать базу данных, где и будет храниться это число, затем написать простой API метод, принимающий это значение для сохранения и второй метод, который это число будет возвращать. Либо это значение уже будет возвращаться в разметке при запросе страницы.

Comment: К сожалению я не разу не работал с базой данных и с api есть какя-нибуть документация или что то подобное

Comment: @TOOM_TYM, Выберите язык программирования, на котором хотите дальше разрабатывать веб-приложения и для этого языка выберите фреймворк. Например, для PHP - Laravel, для Python - Django, для Java - Spring, для C# - ASP.Net Core, для JavaScript не разрабатывал, но, может тот же Express.js. Далее уже по первым же урокам сможете сделать то, что Вам нужно