# Как читать и вывести данные из local storage?

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Имеются записи в local storage вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в html получить и вывести эти данные шаблонно?

```
#555
   artikul: ?
   category: ?
   ...
#556
   artikul: ?
   category: ?
   ...
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что это localStorage? localStorage это строка с определенным ключем. А у вас объект

Comment: Да и про "вывести эти данные шаблонно" не особо понятно...

Comment: https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=js+localstorage+read+write

Comment: @SwaD, в просмотрщике браузера элементы отображаются как объекты

Comment: @ksa, Чтобы не путались данные друг с другом.

Comment: Ты знаешь - ситуация не особо прояснилась...

Comment: [Как записать и прочитать данные из localStarage](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452944/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-localstorage/1452946#1452946) - вдруг поможет...